# Wordpress: list custom post type by category or tag

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories

I have created a custom type, with categories and tags:

```
function servicios_taxonomy() {  
    register_taxonomy(  
        'servicios_categories',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces). 
        'servicios',        //post type name
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => true,  
            'label' => 'Categorías servicios',  //Display name
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'servicios', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                'with_front' => false // Display the category base before 
            )
        )  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'init', 'servicios_taxonomy');

function create_posttype() {
    $args = array(
        'labels'              => array(
                                     'name' => __( 'Servicios' ),
                                     'singular_name' => __( 'Servicio' )
                                 ),
        'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'servicios'),
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'taxonomies'          => array('servicios_categories', 'post_tag'),
        'has_archive'         => true,
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */  
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 20,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page'
    );

    register_post_type( 'servicios',$args);

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

I can access all custom posts in url `http://example.com/servicios` but when adding menu entries with *servicios* categories in menu editor, I get urls in the form `http://example.com/category-slug/servicios` and it leads to a *sorry your search returned no results* page.

The same happens when I click in a tag in this custom post type view, the link `http://example.com/tag/custom-post-tag/`.

What do I need to do to list custom post types by category or tag?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the Wordpress query for category and archive pages by including the following code in the `functions.php` file to include both regular posts and your custom post type:

```
function my_post_queries( $query ) {
  if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()){
    // alter the query for the archive and category pages 
    if( is_category() || is_archive() ){
            $query->set('post_type', array('servicios', 'post') );
            $query->set('post_status', 'publish');
            $query->set('orderby', 'date');
    }
  }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_post_queries' );
```

(This can include more settings/conditions/arguments, but that's how it looks basically)

Comment: This did the job for tags (`http://example.com/tag/custom-post-tag/`) but not for categories (`http://example.com/category-slug/servicios`), maybe some parameter in custom post type registration? Thank you

Comment: I think the link for categories should be "http://example.com/category/category-slug/", just as for regular category pages (at least I use it that way)

Comment: Same result with that, *sorry your search returned no results*

Comment: Possibly in this line ` 'taxonomies'  => array('servicios_categories', 'post_tag'),` -> not 'servicios_categories', but regular categories / 'post_category' (?)

Comment: Well, it works this way though it forces me to use regular categories, I'd prefer to keep them separate (I have a bunch of categories already assigned) but I have a solution now. Thanks!

Comment: An additional thought: `is_category()`  only applies to regular category pages, so try to replace `is_category()` with  `is_post_type_archive( 'servicios' )`

Comment: Finally I did it with regular categories, as this last option wasn't working too.